# How to pass Activity like parameter

Tags: android

I have to open a new Activity and save the address of the previous activity, so I pass the first activity like parameter and then I try to assign it in a variable in the new activity.

This is the listener of first activity:

```
public class ChronometerListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    ChronometerActivity activity;
    public ChronometerListener(ChronometerActivity activity) {
        this.activity=activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EventoActivity eventoActivity = new EventoActivity();

        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.giocatoreBtn:
            eventoActivity.startActivity(activity, 0, getOra(), activity.getPartitaModel(), activity.getTempo());
            break;
    // [....]
}
```

This is the second activity:

```
public class EventoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ChronometerActivity chronometerActivity;
    public void startActivity(ChronometerActivity activity, int ruolo, String ora, PartitaModel partitaModel,
                            String tempo) {
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putSerializable("partitaModel", partitaModel);
        extras.putString("tempo", tempo);
        extras.putInt("ruolo", ruolo);
        extras.putString("cronometro", activity.getCronometroTextView().getText().toString());
        extras.putString("ora", ora);
        chronometerActivity = activity;

        // Create and start intent for this Activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, EventoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

So I use the function startActivity to start the second activity where activity is not null but chronometerActivity is always null. How can I assign activity to chronometerActivity?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow! At first glance I would say that the main problem is not the passing of the activity, it is more like the fact, that you have to pass. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have to create various activitys where I have to pass some variables to first activity

Comment: First of all, try to use fragments, it seems like the viewmodell, or something like the viewmodell is a good solution for you at this case, only if you switch to fragments. If you do not want to switch to fragments I would advise to create some kind of manager object to store the required data, this can use shared preferences, or just simple local data.

Comment: You definitely do not want to be saving your activities in variables like this, it is an easy way to create memory leaks

Comment: @barotia I prefer to create a manager, is there any guide that can help me?

Comment: @Quinn can you explain?

Comment: Well, speaking about the manager part, it depends on the complexity of the project. If you do not want to overcomplicate it, just create a singleton for that, I would not advise that in all case, but it seems that it just meets the requirements for the moment.

Comment: @SimoneRusso Basically, there will only be one activity active at a time, when you use the startActivity(intent), android will detach one activity and attach the next - the garbage collector would want too free up memory from the first activity, but it you hold onto a reference to it it won't be able to free that memory.